# env values from Linux not loaded by Laravel config app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

[Some time ago I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789424/laravel-env-settings-use-config-app-php) about setting env settings and how to properly use them. I was quickly pointed to a comparable question and I found out that indeed it was bad practice to use env('KEY') throughout your code.

So now I am in the process of migrating my env settings to config/app.php.

However, if I play with Tinker, the env variables from Linux are not loaded by Laravel. For instance, if I place:

```
'test' => 'testing123',
```

within the config/app.php

and do a

```
sudo php artisan config:cache
```

and employ Tinker

> > > config('app.test');
> > >          => "testing123"

So that seems to work. However, if I place the following

```
'test' => env('DB_PORT'),
```

and do a

```
sudo php artisan config:cache
```

and test this with tinker:

> > > config('app.test');
> > >          => null

But when I am in the console and use:

```
env|grep DB_PORT
```

I see the right value for the DB_PORT key. I am supplying these in AWS frontend, these properties are then passed in the application as environment properties.

Anyone any idea why these are not imported/loaded correctly?

Comment: Ah it seems that my Laravel is not running as the ec2-user which I am when I login. So the env settings are fine for ec2-user.

Comment: Can you use tutorials to learn? https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/6

Comment: thanks, that's a good one. I found why my laravel wasn't working. I had to remove the bootstrape/cache/config.php and after that... it worked..

Comment: Write the answer please. And first, you must search a little before ask here...

Answer (score 0):

php artisan config:clear
Or you can just manually delete bootstrap/config.php, which is what artisan does after all.

See: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigClearCommand.php